# Permission issue for MS ACCESS file while create setup of c# window application

Tags: c#, vb.net

We are in process of creating a .Net application ( c#, VS2013 with Access Database). We are using install shield to create an installer. Installer works fine when we choose D drive as target. However it fails when C drive is chosen. I am assuming its some kind of permission error. Can someone give some insights on why its failing only in c drive? What am I missing?

[Click here to see the error that i am getting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOJxL.png)

Thanks

Comment: Try running the installer via "Run as administrator" option in the context menu. Mostly this fixes everything. It seems your OS is Windows 8 and above, so even if you are logged as an administrator, do this.

Comment: i did that,but still have same issue.

Comment: If that is so [check this out, ignore the title but follow the steps as mentioned](http://dailyapps.net/hack-attack-disable-uac-for-certain-applications-in-vista/)

Comment: are you a local administrator of the computer where you are trying to install the application? Also, there are a few folders in OS drive (i.e., c: drive in your case) where you can't install other softwares. So make sure you are installing at correct location.

Comment: Whats the error message? what does the install log say? when you install it with ProcessMonitor running does it work otherwise show us the ProcessMonitor error?

Comment: Default location for installation is C:\Program Files.i can give option to change installation location but cant tell client that you can not install this setup in C:\Program Files.

Comment: The error message seems to have nothing to do with c:\program files.  It appears to refer to deleting from some Excel files?  Does your installer try to install some files on users desktop?

Comment: no,i am just reading xls files data and and save data in ACCESS file.before save it i am just deleting old data from ACCESS database.